# Whats the difference between vi editor in Red Hat linux and Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, vi

I realize a difference in vi editor of ReD Hat and Ubuntu. In my company, I'm working in Red Hat. In that, the vi editing commands working as usual. Say, 'dd' to delete,'p' to paste, 'yy' to yank, etc. But in Ubuntu, if I open the vi editor in terminal, then the commands are not working properly.

Even to switch vi to Insert mode, I am supposed to press 'I' many times. I can type coding after some struggle. I can't delete a letter by pressing 'Delete' button. If I press 'Up', 'Down','Left', 'Right' keys, then some alphabets are being written in it.

Why this is happening? How to resolve it? Is this because of Ubuntu?

Comment: Probably, different versions or, most likely, on the one place, `vi` is really `vi`, on the other - `vi` is `alias` for `'vim'`.

Comment: Nope. I suspect unset TERM variable (or wrong value). is this perhaps over ssh/screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with vim-tiny, which IMHO sucks.

you need to install vim

do

> sudo apt-get install vim

Comment: That doesn't explain the differences that Dinesh is seeing. Those basic commands work in vim-tiny as well as in the larger versions.

Comment: ubuntu's vi defaults to vi(original) compatibility mode. which behaves like this . To disable it in vi(default) in ubuntu: `:set nocompatible`. refer [bug reported](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/70569).

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the arrows not working by adding the .vimrc file in my home directory.  I found the answer [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell), under "Additional solution 5".  All I have in the file is "set nocompatible", as mentioned above.

However, I highly recommend you installing the full version of vim as Mr. Divekar mentions above.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to install `vim`, or any other flavor of vim to fix the problem. Just change a setting:

`sh -c 'echo "set nocompatible" >> ~/.vimrc'`

That's all.

If this does not resolve it, *and* the problem is that it is happening over ssh, then when you are in vim or vi, do this command first of all:
`:set term=cons25`